# Magento 1.9 : Custom option not work in product page

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I have a product that has multiple prices
When I do not set the custom option, for example, 1400 will be displayed
But when I customize the option, the 1400 number becomes 1
But in the basket everything is right
This problem is only on the product page

[1] : https://pasteboard.co/It4NLeg.jpg
[2] : https://pasteboard.co/It4PfhFc.png

The purchase price of this product is 1000 when i add a custom option and add 1400, price of product changed to 10
Where can the problem be?

Comment: please attach the screenshot of product price and custom option

Comment: i add screen shot @JigsParmar